# Unable to do WP_User_Query with meta filter

Tags: taxonomy, terms, user-meta, wp-user-query

I have a user base of hundreds of users, and trying to create a custom API endpoint to get users in a specific membership group.

The database structure is as follows (**using Ultimate Member plugin**):

- User is stored in `wpma_users` table
- User metadata in table `wpma_usermeta` contains user meta named `mygroups`, containing a value `a:1:{i:0;s:3:"155";}`
- The `155` value is the ID of a term

I already tried this, with `$groupid=155`:

```
$args = array(
            'fields'    => 'all_with_meta',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'mygroups',
                  'field' => 'term_id',
                  'terms' => $groupid,
                ),
            ),
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

When I var_dump `get_terms(array('include' => $groupid))`, an actual term is printed:

```
array(1){
    [
        0
    ]=>object(WP_Term)#27633(10){
        [
            "term_id"
        ]=>int(155)[
            "name"
        ]=>string(8)"Example Group"[
            "slug"
        ]=>string(8)"example_group"[
            "term_group"
        ]=>int(0)[
            "term_taxonomy_id"
        ]=>int(155)[
            "taxonomy"
        ]=>string(11)"um_user_tag"[
            "description"
        ]=>string(0)""[
            "parent"
        ]=>int(149)[
            "count"
        ]=>int(1)[
            "filter"
        ]=>string(3)"raw"
    }
}
```

Another way I tried, is using the `meta_query` instead of the tax_query:

```
'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'mygroups',
                'value' => $groupid,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
),
```

This actually filters the query, but when I use `$groupid=1`, it filters where `groupid` contains `1`, so also `10`, `11`, `100` etc.

Who can point me in the right direction to filter the user on `mygroups` the right way?

Comment: You need to ask this in an Ultimate Member plugin community, this isn't possible using generic WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, since the serialized array is always structured like this: `':"%s";'`, it is possible to write a meta_query like:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'mygroups',
        'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', $groupid),
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible, you can't safely/reliably query the internals of meta value strings that way, and you can't use it as a form of indirection:

- You can query for substrings or for whole values, but you can't query the internals of serialised PHP values without major performance reliability and consistency issues
- but if you could, or if it was just the plain number, there's no way to then take that and plug it into a term query
- You can only use `tax_query` to find users in a given taxonomy, but your users don't have terms, and they aren't in a taxonomy.

User taxonomies are a thing, so be careful about what you're asking. Instead, you need to rephrase your question like this:

> How do I find users with a specific value that's listed in the `mygroups` user meta field using `WP_User_Query`?

And the answer is, you can't. This is because `mygroups` is stored as a serialised PHP array, and you can't query sub-values of serialised values. E.g. you could use a LIKE style parameter to search for group 1 but it will also give you 10, 100, 41, etc It may even give you users who have a group number that is 1 digit long, and users that have 1 group even if that groups number is 9999.

It may be that there is a solution that uses features of the Ultimate Member plugin, but questions about that plugin and other 3rd party plugins are off-topic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer! Also, thanks for your clarification about taxonomies and terms. Since I could get specific terms with the Wordpress get_terms($id) method, I thought it would maybe be possible with native Wordpress filtering. I'll try the Ultimate Member form.